# Calculating positive elements of $a_n$ with formula for $a_{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I know this is a very simple high-school problem, but there is one detail that won't let me sleep.

The question:

*For all $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies following equations:*
$$
a_n+a_{n+1}=\frac{-n^2+3n+17}{n^2+1}\\
a_n-a_{n+1}=\frac{6n+19}{n^2+1}
$$
*Calculate which elements of the sequence are positive.*

Of course the task is very easy, you just need to add these two equations to get the formula for $a_n$ and from there you get that $a_n$ is positive when $n\in(-3;12)$, so the elements we are looking for are: $a_1,a_2,...,a_{11}$.

However, my student asked me why when trying to derive formula for $a_{n+1}$ instead of $a_n$ (by substracting these two equations), we get completely different (and wrong) answer, instead of just shifting the interval by $1$.

Unfortunately I couldn't answer his question, could you enlighten me?

Comment: Does this sequence even exist?   You have two recursive definitions for it, each of the form $a_{n+1}=Ca_n+P(n)$ for a constant $C$ and a polynomial $P(n)$.  Why should these define the same sequence?

Comment: As a suggestion to see the contradiction more plainly, use the original method to write out several terms of the sequence.  Now ask if the two recursions hold.

Comment: @lulu I don't know, this is a question from a textbook, I didn't alter it.

Comment: Ok.  But then I think it is not so very simple after all.  Good exercise in the dangers of manipulating definitions without confirming that they are consistent!    As a cheap illustration of the problem here, suppose you tried to define a sequence $\{b_n\}$ via $b_n-b_{n+1}=1$ and $b_n+b_{n-1}=1$.  Adding tells us that $b_n\equiv 1$ but that obviously satisfies neither recursion.

Comment: @lulu so the question is wrong, because these two equations are inconsistent?

Comment: Not sure I'd say "wrong", it just has a more subtle answer than you were expecting.  What reference are you using?

Comment: Note:  I had a typo in my example from above.  The second recursion was meant to read $b_n+b_{n+1}=1$.

Comment: @lulu yes, yes I saw that typo. Anyway, what would be the correct answer if the question isn't contradictory?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense.  If I say "consider a function $F(x)$ with $F(x)=x+1$ and $F(x)=2x$ find $F(0)$"  the answer is that $F(x)$ is undefined.  There is no function that satisfies the rules I set.

Comment: @lulu so the question is "wrong"?

Comment: You can, of course, come up with a consistent problem along the same lines.  Take an actual sequence, like $A_n=\frac {n^2-6n-2}{n^2+2}$ and sort out what $A_n\pm A_{n+1}$ are.  We know that's consistent.  Again, I don't like the word "wrong" here. The response "no such sequence exists" is a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The problem here is that the two recursions are not consistent.  As a result there is no such sequence and the problem can not be answered as stated.

To illustrate the problem, consider a simpler example:

$$b_b-b_{n+1}=1\quad \&\quad b_n+b_{n+1}=1$$

Adding we get $b_n\equiv 1$ while subtracting yields $b_n\equiv 0$.  Again, the issue is that the two recursions are inconsistent.

I don't know that it's obvious that the given pair of recursions is inconsistent.  The students method (computing $a_{n+1}$ in two ways and getting two different answers) may well be optimal or close to it.  As another method, you can use the closed form "solution" obtained via addition and check whether or not it satisfies the two recursions.